# Black screen after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, lts

I had Ubuntu 14.04 running on my Dell Vostro. I started upgrading it through the update manager. It downloaded all the required packages, installed them and (probably) restarted.

When I checked back after about 30 minutes, I was at the login screen. I entered my username and password and since then it's stuck at a black screen with the blinking cursor.

No keys are working except for the power button - which simply switches off the computer after showing a bunch of "stopped xxxxxxxxx" scripts.

Sorry as I couldn't add more details. This is what all I could post through my phone.

Here's what the otherwise empty screen shows before shutting down when I press the power button:
[image]

After leaving for about 30 minutes, it shows me this:
[image]

And it remains here forever.

Answer (score 0):

I propose first to burn an ISO-CD and run Ubuntu in Test Mode in a ramdisk. 
Here we (maybe) see if generally the thing works. 
Upgrade to 16.04-64?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out what to do. So, as the last option, I made a bootable USB for 14.04, logged in through it and copied all my important files to an external hard drive.

After that, I installed 14.04, erasing everything that was there earlier.